# url rewrite in asp.net for dynamially generated urls

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I have few dinamically generated urls like `http://localhost:35228/begineercontent?name=lanaguages&id=23`, I used routing to hide .aspx extension and now i want to see above url like this `http://localhost:35228/begineercontent/lanaguages/23` i tried few url rewrite methods from iis url rewrite tool nothing worked kindly please help me out

Answer (score 0):

This can be done very easy. You need to change/add this code in your global.asax.

```
void registerroute(RouteCollection routes)
{

       routes.MapPageRoute("begineercontent", "begineercontent/languages/{Id}", "~/begineercontent.aspx");
 }

void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            // Code that runs on application startup
            registerroute(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

You also need to include the right assembly in global.asax by adding

```
using System.Web.Routing
```

In your begineercontent.aspx you need to add this code to the page load function.

```
var Id=( Page.RouteData.Values["Id"] as string);
```

A more detailled tutorial on how to work with routes can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc668177%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: i did as you said but there is no difference in the url @user3786513